# What to know about PMD Pro vs PMP

Tags: pmp, certification

I am currently wondering about the differences between PMP and PMD Pro and what are the pros and cons of both certifications.

If you can you help me here, then do it.

Answer (score 1):

PMD Pro (Project Management for Development Professionals) was developed in partnership with [PM4NGOs](https://www.pm4ngos.org/) (Project Management for NGOs), an organization dedicated to optimizing international project investments and improving professional project management skills in the development sector.

PMD Pro is an adaptation of the [PMBOK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Management_Body_of_Knowledge) (Project Management Body Of Knowledge) methodology and other successful business methodologies to the social sector reality.

Based on the [PMI](https://www.pmi.org/) (Project Management Institute), the methodology systematizes the concepts and techniques of project management, teaching how to apply project management concepts to the specific context of social projects.

**The main difference** between PMD Pro and PMP is that the first works with means of impact measurement, human development, quality of life and risk mitigation that are not commonly used in the business market hence why it appeared.

When it comes to **the benefits** for PMD Pro, [PM4NGOs](https://www.pm4ngos.org/pmdpro-story/) states the following three

> 1. *On Time*
>
> NGOs using PMD Pro report reduced delays because PMD Pro tools help
>   development staff define project risks and goals, assess progress, and
>   efficiently delegate work.
>
> 2. *On Budget*
>
> NGOs using PMD Pro report improved cost management, enhanced donor
>   reporting, and more confident project and program staff.
>
> 3. *Proven Results*
>
> Project stakeholders report benefits from increased transparency,
>   common vocabulary and improved project outcomes.

(*To note*: one can find other reasons why to take this course in firms where it's possible to book the exam (for instances [APMG International](https://apmg-international.com/product/pmd-pro) and [Humentum](https://www.humentum.org/training/project-management-development-professionals-pmd-pro)).)

There are at least two acceptable QAs on if one should take PMP certification

- [Is the PMP or other project management certification worth while to have?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/871/27189)
- [How important are PMI certifications in the beginning of a PM career?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/16876/27189)

Answer (score 0):

Stakeholder management strategy is also a key focus in project DPro. It is one of the factors that distinguishes it and makes it more relevant in the development sector. Working in the development sector requires interfacing with various internal and external stakeholders. Managing them becomes a challenge if not we'll handled. This is why project DPro guides on how to excel in this

Answer (score 0):

It can be crucial for people pursuing Project Management Professionaln(PMP) certification to recognize the differences between PMD Pro and PMP. Here’s a unique breakdown that might clarify:

**Scope:**

**PMD Prof:** Primarily specializes in performance management for improvement initiatives, mainly inside the global improvement sector. It highlights projects that goal to bring about superb social exchange or development.

**PMP:** Covers venture control principles and pleasant practices throughout industries and industries, from records era to manufacturing to healthcare. It is wellknown in scope and applies to a extensive range of responsibilities and contexts.

**Target Audience:**

**PMD Pro:** Intended for managers and experts running in worldwide development projects, along with NGOs, not-for-profit businesses and government corporations worried in development initiatives.

**PMP:** Targets managers and specialists across industries and industries, inclusive of IT, era, healthcare, finance, and greater. It is suitable for anybody concerned in undertaking control, no matter the unique challenge.

**Certification Organization:**

**PMD Pro:** Managed with the aid of APMG International, a global accreditation body specializing in venture control requirements and abilties.

**PMP:** Offered via the Project Management Institute (PMI), one of the maximum identified and respected companies in the discipline of mission management.

**Focus on development initiatives:**

**PMD Prof:** There is a strong emphasis on monitoring targeted tasks for social impact or improvement, along with poverty comfort, fitness reform, schooling, and infrastructure development.

**PMP:** Provides a complete approach to project management, consisting of standards, methods, and.